# い-adj in く form + する what is the meaning?

Tags: adverbs, i-adjectives, newspaper-grammar

I was reading an article at nhk news web site and I found a sentence which I'm not pretty sure what the meaning really is.
Here's a fragment:

試験ではまず、日本の県や町などで、将来どんな問題が起こるかが書いてある文章を読みます。そして、どうやってその問題をなくしたらいいか、スマートフォンやパソコンを使って情報を集めて、レポートを書きます。大学は、試験を受ける人が外にいる人にメールなどで試験の問題を送ったりしないように、チェックする人を多くします。

What i'm a little bit concerned about is the 多くします part.
多く is an adverb which means something like: a lot, much, abundant so I might think that the meaning would be something like " to do very much" or "to do something with frequency"
Am I right?
Please help.

Answer (score 4):

The cut down sentence is:

> 大学はチェックする人を多くします。
> The universities will make sure there are a lot of people to check (on the students)

Literally "The universities will make the people doing the checking many".

This usage of adverbs with する happens a lot, and you can't normally translate the adverb as an English adverb without it sounding really awkward; 'many-ly' is not a word.
Another example which instantly springs to mind is 部屋をきれいにする (cleanly make the room = make the room clean = clean the room).