Creating a verb from an い adjective by dropping い and replacing with くする?
I know that you can make an adverb from an い adjective by replacing い with く.
早い - fast
早く - quickly
One of the things I ran into while studying was "Please don't make it too short" by using this: あまり短くしないで下さい。
In this example, it looks like 短い becomes 短くする for "to make short." Is this common to see 〜い become 〜くする for this, or is this just an off-by-one use case?

A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar lists 〜くする as a possible usage, corresponding to the use of 〜にする for nouns and な-adjectives.

Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83193/9831

https://bunpro.jp/grammar_points/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%8F%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B
